# blinking external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

I dropped my Seagate external hard drive not so high probably around 1 to 1.5 foot and now I cannot access it, what it does is it just keeps on blinking. Any ideas how do I troubleshoot it? It's already pretty old, probably around 3 years.

Comment: What's the particular model?

Comment: 3.5 inch or 2.5 inch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SeaTools for Windows located here http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/item/seatools-win-master/

If SeaTools won't detect it, I would break the drive out of it's enclosure and try again with it directly connected.

Comment: While dropping the drive probably would void the warranty, opening it up definately would. Worth keeping in mind.